# Hashed passwords and PasswordRecovery control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership

1)  firstUser was created when membership module had requiresQuestionAndAnswer set to false, while secondUser was created when requiresQuestionAndAnswer was set to true.

- If we try to recover pwd via PasswordRecovery PR control and we set requiresQuestionAndAnswer to true, then PR doesn’t email password to firstUser, but it does to secondUser.
- If we set requiresQuestionAndAnswer to false, then PR does email pwd to secondUser (it skips the question/answer stage). But why doesn’t PR also email pwd to firstUser?

2) I’ve read somewhere that if membership provider stores password in hashed form,  then the PR will generate a new pwd and email it to the user. But instead I get an exception. Is there some property we must configure for PR to generate new pwd and email it?

thanx

UPDATE:

1) For some reason it works now. Namely, if we set requiresQuestionAndAnswer to false, then PR also sends email to firstUser

2)  If passwords are stored in hashed form, then if:

a) *enablePasswordRetrieval="true"* and *enablePasswordReset* is set to either *true* or *false* --> PR generates exception

b) if *enablePasswordRetrieval="false"* and *enablePasswordReset="false"* --> PR generates exception

c) if *enablePasswordRetrieval* is set to false and *enablePasswordReset* is set to *true*, then PR automatically generates new pwd and emails it.

Similarly, if pwd is not hashed, but we have *enablePasswordRetrieval="false"*, then *enablePasswordReset* must be set to true (so that PR generates a new pwd and emails it), else we get an exception

Comment: What is the exception you get in the second case? Most likely you haven't configured the mail bits . . .

Comment: I don't get an exception. i get "Your attempt to retrieve your password was not successful. Please try again."I checked whether SendingMail event was raised for firstUser, and it wasn't

Comment: thanks for updating your question with the answer. worked for me

Answer (score 1):

if you want to generate your own password and you have q&a set to true, you need to make a second membership provider.

Here is a link:  http://peterkellner.net/2007/02/15/resetpasswordaspnet/