# ASP PasswordRecovery Email Failure, DateTime precision

Tags: asp.net, datetime, smtp, password-recovery

I have an asp.net 4.0 website and I'm using the PasswordRecovery control for a forgot password form. When I run the site locally it works fine, emails are sent. However, when I run the site from  my vps, I get an error message when trying to send the email. There's nothing in the server's event log.

My PasswordRecovery aspx code is as follows:

```
 <asp:PasswordRecovery ID="PasswordRecovery1" runat="server"       
            CssClass="mediumText">
            <MailDefinition From="noreply@x.com"   BodyFileName="~/EmailTemplates/PasswordRecovery.txt" />
```

My web.config mail settings are as follows:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="noreply@x.com">
        <network host="smtp.123-reg.co.uk" password="x" userName="x" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

I've now run SQL Profiler against the SQL Server Express Instance, and it turns out that an exception is being thrown from the SQL Server on the call to `dbo.aspnet_Membership_GetUserByName`. There's a type conversion issue because PasswordRecovery is passing a `DateTime` parameter with 7 decimal places for the seconds. If I manually execute the stored procedure with 3 decimal place,s then it works. Does anyone know why the precision of the `DateTime` parameter is different on my server than on my laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you will see from reading [this issue](http://forums.asp.net/t/1398826.aspx/1) and the subsequent responses, the `DateTime` precision issue you are seeing is just a result of SQL Profiler displaying the date with the wrong format. That issue is unrelated to what is preventing your email from being sent.

What is the error message you receive when you try to send the email? The issue is more than likely related to something preventing your email from making it to the SMTP server. Are you sending to the same SMTP using the same credentials from your machine?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same credentials when sending SMTP email from my laptop and the server. I don't get to seen any error details because I'm using the PasswordRecovery control. I guess that's the trade-off with the "easy" controls :(

Comment: Do you have access to the server, or is it on a hosting service? If you have access, can you try telneting to the destination SMTP server to see if something is blocking the traffic. If you don't have access because it is on a hosting service, you should probably read the hosting service's knowledge base or contact their support to determine what their requirements are for sending out mail over SMTP.

Comment: yes I have full access to the VPS. I am able to connect to the SMTP server via telnet and actually send an email from my VPS. This is what makes me think that the problem is not an SMTP issue. Also, why does SQL profiler show only 3 decimal points for the seconds when the website runs on my laptop?

Comment: @RobBowman In the problem description, you say that you receive an error message when trying to send an email. What is the error message? On the SQL Profiler issue, are you running the exact same version of SQL and SQL Profiler as on the server?

Comment: The error message I get from the PasswordRecovery control is "Your attempt to retrieve your password was not successful. Please try again." I've now configured my VPS as an SMTP server and tested that I can send an email from the command line by following a great post at: http://www.chrislazari.com/2011/04/iis-75-installing-smtp-service-securing.html 
I've configured my website to use the local SMTP server but I'm still getting the error. Re version of SQL / Profiler, on my laptop I'm it's SQL Server Stnd, on the VPS it's SQL Express and https://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/ (both 64bit)

Comment: @RobBowman, the fact that you don't get an actual exception makes me think it is not an SMTP issue. An SMTP exception should be logged in the event log. Is it possible something is wrong with the account you are trying to recover the password for? Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534015/hashed-passwords-and-passwordrecovery-control

Answer (score 0):

I think it is some connectivity issue from your VPS to SMTP server.
You can test this outside of your code by trying to connect to SMTP server using telnet. 
Follow the steps mentioned in the link below to 
         http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323350

Comment: I have used telnet to send email from my VPS via the remote SMTP server, this works fine

Comment: @rob bowman I don't know which version of SQL server you are using in production and which vervesrion was used in development and testing. It sounds like in development at some point you have used datetime2 and now you are trying to use datetime. Hence your 3 vs 7 decimal precision issue. Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350066/linq-to-entities-produces-query-containing-datetime2-on-sql-2005-express

Answer (score 0):

The datetime conversion error is a red herring.  That is only occuring when you copy it from the profiler and execute it in management studio.  This is a known issue.

You might want to read this:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1398826.aspx/1

Sounds like it might simply be that the membership provider settings are different with regards to the passwords.

There are two possibilities that I see.

1. You don't have a machineKey defined in your web.config AND your local and VPS instance are both pointing to the same database.  If this is true, put a machineKey in your config and regen your passwords.
2. Your membership provider config on the VPS used to be configured for hashed passwords and somewhere along the way was changed to encrypted passwords.  (or vice versa).  This would also cause issues.